# Why does it keep on duplicating the current row I’m updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I’ve been encountering another problem from the last code I’ve posted: it keeps on duplicating the current row I’m updating. The code for updating the row is fine, it stays at the same position not below all the rows, but the only problem is that it duplicates the current row I’m updating. This is my last problem and my code is done. Hope y’all could help me.

```js
function remove(deletelink) {
  $(deletelink).closest("tr").remove();
  
  if ($("tbody").find("tr").length == 0) {
    $("tbody").append("<tr id='nomore'><td colspan='4'>No more records.</td></tr>");
  }
  
  return false;
}

function edit(editlink) {
  var name = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.name").text();
  var course = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.course").text();

  $("#name").val(name);
  $("#course").val(course);
  $("#button").val("SAVE");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let row = null;

  //DELETE RECORD
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    remove(this);
  });

  //EDIT RECORD    
  $(".edit").click(function() {
    row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('#name').val(row.find('td:eq(0)').text())
    $('#course').val(row.find('td:eq(1)').text())
    edit(this);
  });


  $("#button").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var course = $("#course").val();

    //REMOVE "NO MRORE RECORDS WHEN ADDING"
    if ($("tbody").find("tr#nomore").length > 0) {
      $("tbody").html("");
    }

    //ADD RECORD
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");

    //UPDATE RECORD
    if (row) {
      row.find('td:eq(0)').text($('#name').val());
      row.find('td:eq(1)').text($('#course').val());
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#course').val('');
    }

    //DELETE THE NEWLY UPDATED RECORD
    $(".delete").click(function() {});
    $(".delete").click(function() {
      remove(this);
    });

    //EDIT RECORD AFTER DELETING
    $(".edit").click(function() {});
    $(".edit").click(function() {
      edit(this);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <input type="text" id="course" placeholder="Course" />
  <input type="button" id="button" value="ADD" />
  <br /><br />
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Joaquin</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jump</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Ersan</td>
        <td class="course">BSHRM</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Laree</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why are you adding a record each time the button is clicked? $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");

Comment: If you [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code, you should be able to answer your own question. You can also try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: You also have multiple places that you are adding the click handlers. When you call `$(".edit")` (same for delete) it is finding all the edit buttons on the page and adding another click handler. When the button is clicked, it calls every one of those handlers. When adding a row, you should find only the `.edit` and `.delete` on that row and add the handler there or use a parent element that doesn't go away like `$('table').on('click', '.edit', function(){ ... })` which will put the handler on the table, but only respond when the edit button is clicked.

Comment: @Xufox You should definitely add that _RDD_ to [**this**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/).

Answer (score 1):

If the record is going to be updated then no need to add it in table.

**Modified code:**

```
//UPDATE RECORD
if (row) {
  row.find('td:eq(0)').text($('#name').val());
  row.find('td:eq(1)').text($('#course').val());
  $('#name').val('');
  $('#course').val('');
}
else
{
//ADD RECORD
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
 }
```

**Full code:**

```js
function remove(deletelink) {
  $(deletelink).closest("tr").remove();
  
  if ($("tbody").find("tr").length == 0) {
    $("tbody").append("<tr id='nomore'><td colspan='4'>No more records.</td></tr>");
  }
  
  return false;
}

function edit(editlink) {
  var name = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.name").text();
  var course = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.course").text();

  $("#name").val(name);
  $("#course").val(course);
  $("#button").val("SAVE");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let row = null;

  //DELETE RECORD
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    remove(this);
  });

  //EDIT RECORD    
  $(".edit").click(function() {
    row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('#name').val(row.find('td:eq(0)').text())
    $('#course').val(row.find('td:eq(1)').text())
    edit(this);
  });


  $("#button").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var course = $("#course").val();

    //REMOVE "NO MRORE RECORDS WHEN ADDING"
    if ($("tbody").find("tr#nomore").length > 0) {
      $("tbody").html("");
    }

    //UPDATE RECORD
    if (row) {
      row.find('td:eq(0)').text($('#name').val());
      row.find('td:eq(1)').text($('#course').val());
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#course').val('');
    }
else
{
    //ADD RECORD
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
}

    //DELETE THE NEWLY UPDATED RECORD
    $(".delete").click(function() {});
    $(".delete").click(function() {
      remove(this);
    });

    //EDIT RECORD AFTER DELETING
    $(".edit").click(function() {});
    $(".edit").click(function() {
      edit(this);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <input type="text" id="course" placeholder="Course" />
  <input type="button" id="button" value="ADD" />
  <br /><br />
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Joaquin</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jump</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Ersan</td>
        <td class="course">BSHRM</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Laree</td>
        <td class="course">BSIT</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same button for both add and update. When you are updating, it is calling the append part, which you don't want to do:

```
 //ADD RECORD
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

You need to check if you are adding or editing before this append.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the duplication because your save action has an append in it

```
//ADD RECORD
$("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

Use the `row` variable you are setting as an if condition to see if you should add or edit

```
if(!row){
  $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
} else {
  row.find('td:eq(0)').text($('#name').val());
  row.find('td:eq(1)').text($('#course').val());
  $('#name').val('');
  $('#course').val('');
  //set row back to null
  row=null;    
}
```

You are also creating new click handlers for all your rows each time "Save" is clicked, not just adding a new one to a new row. This will cause duplicated event calls for a single click. Use event delegation and you will only need to setup click handlers once:

```
$("table").on('click','.delete',function() {
  remove(this);
});

//EDIT RECORD               
$("table").on('click','.edit',function() {
  row = $(this).closest('tr');
  $('#name').val(row.find('td:eq(0)').text())
  $('#course').val(row.find('td:eq(1)').text())
  edit(this);
});
```